# How can I transform a numeric Scala array to be an array of intervals of the values from array?

Tags: arrays, scala

The overall goal is to take a numeric array and convert it to an array of intervals from that array. The intervals can be represented as tuples or arrays. Ultimately these will be converted into strings anyway. For example I would like Array(0,1,2,3) to become Array("0 to 1", "1 to 2", "2 to 3")

Here are some examples:

**Example 1**

Input: `Array(0,1,2,3)`

Output: `Array((0,1), (1,2), (2,3))`

**Example 2**

Input: `Array(Double.NegativeInfinity,0,1,2,3,Double.PositiveInfinity)`

Output: `Array((Double.NegativeInfinity,0), (0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,Double.PositiveInfinity))`

Comment: While learning stay away from **Arrays**, they are mutable, they are invariant, and they aren't a real collection but a **JVM** primitive. Use **Lists** or **Vectors** or any other real collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `sliding(2)` does on a Scala collection

```
scala> Array(0,1,2,3).sliding(2).toList
val res1: List[Array[Int]] = List(Array(0, 1), Array(1, 2), Array(2, 3))
```

```
scala> Array(Double.NegativeInfinity,0,1,2,3,Double.PositiveInfinity).sliding(2).toList
val res7: List[Array[Double]] = List(Array(-Infinity, 0.0), Array(0.0, 1.0), Array(1.0, 2.0), Array(2.0, 3.0), Array(3.0, Infinity))
```

To take the output from sliding and make the strings "0 to 1", "1 to 2", etc as you note you can use `map` and String interpolation. The `{}` brackets are necessary to interpolate the values (`arr(i)`) in the array.

```
Array(0,1,2,3).sliding(2).map(arr => s"${arr(0)} to ${arr(1)}").toList
val res19: List[String] = List(0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve that just by zipping the collection with itself dropping the first element:

```scala
val arr = Array(0,1,2,3)
arr
  .zip(arr.drop(1))
```